# Update Entities with currentUser-ID

Tags: persistence, entity, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

I'm trying to update each entity with an own `@EntityListeners({ ModelListener.class })`.
`ModelListener` implements `@PrePersist` with a method like this:

```
@PrePersist
protected void prePersist(final ModelBase modelBase) {
    modelBase.setUpdatedBy(currentUser);}
```

My question is how to get the current user.
I already tried several things:

**1) transport the information over EJB**

```
    @EJB
private UserModul userModul;
```

The `userModul` is always null, when `prePersist` is called. It seems the EJB-context is not available.

**2) Fill a static ThreadLocal**

```
static ThreadLocal<User> currentUser = new ThreadLocal<User>();
```

Because of the static attribute each classloader (each request in webservers) holds its own instance. I tried with a `@WebFilter` to fill the `ThreadLocal`. But it seems I have no faces context.

```
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, ...){
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();} //always null
```

Also in request (`com.sun.enterprise.web.pwc.connector.coyote.PwcCoyoteRequest`) I don't find any information of loggedin user.

What is the most common way to save user information?

Comment: If I get it right, you have the userid saved in the webcontainer and you want to access it in the ejb container from the jpa entity lifecycle event callback method. Right?

Comment: What is your main goal? Can you give us the context?